# Mapping source file to recipes in yocto

Tags: yocto, recipe

To edit source in Yocto, I have to execute `devtool modify <recipe>`. I know the name of the source file, say `foo.cpp`, **not** the recipe. Using information captured elsewhere I can find out which recipe corresponds to my source file. To me that's the brute force method. Is there a recommended way to find the recipe using Yocto tools?

I have already viewed dependencies and reverse dependencies with **Toaster**. That did not help.

Comment: Its unusual and awkward to now the source file but not the recipe. There could be multiple recipies with the same name of the source file (main.c). You should elaborate on "Using information captured elsewhere I can find out which recipe corresponds to my source file." What do you do exactly and please explain why. Then I can try to show you the recommended workflow

Comment: Some source files are stored with a directory in the file path corresponding to recipe name. That method did not apply to all sources. Moreover, the file names I am searching for are unique. @FlorianBerndl What is the recommended workflow?